# Remove Android App Title Bar

Tags: android, layout, titlebar

I understand that these properties in the manifest:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"     
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

can remove the title bar.
However, I constantly check the Graphical Layout when I am modifying my app. When I look at the Graphical Layout I still see the title bar. I want to remove the title bar in a way that I don't have to see it during the development of the game.

Comment: try this in ur mainfest file:                                                              <application .......
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"    >

Answer (score 87, accepted):

1. In the Design Tab, click on the AppTheme Button
2. Choose the option "AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
3. Click OK.

[image: Row of icons at the top of design view of a layout .xml in Android Studio, The dropdown box with the contrast icon will change the theme.]

Comment: Which version is "current" in your answer?
Can't you just specify the name of the button instead of describing the position of it?
In my "current" version I can't this mysterious button you are talking about...

Comment: really strange answer... just tell me the name of the button to look for. because things have changed, this answer is pretty useless now

Comment: FTR: this answer is over 4 years old and I do not do Android development with Eclipse anymore. If readers know where to find the name of the button (as it changes from version to version), then do not hesitate to edit it in.

Comment: want hide only bottom navigation bar not the status bar. Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 115):

Simple way is to put this in your `onCreate()`:

```java
// Java
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

```kotlin
// Kotlin
supportActionBar?.hide()
```

Comment: I tried all the other answers for this question, but this is the ONLY ANSWER that worked right away!!! Thanks.

Comment: Note that for `ComponentActivity` it is called just `actionBar`

Answer (score 28):

for Title Bar

`requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`

for fullscreen

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Place this after

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

but before

```
setContentView(R.layout.xml);
```

This worked for me.try this

Comment: Putting this after super.onCreate leads to this crash: requestFeature() must be called before adding content

Comment: add that before setcontent(xml)
after super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Comment: Does this still work in Marshmallow? Doesn't seem to.

Answer (score 28):

I was able to do this for Android 2.1 devices and above using an App Compatibility library theme applied to the app element in the manifest:

```
<application
    ...
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />

<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    ...
   <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
   <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Note: You will need to include the `com.android.support:appcompat-v7`library in your build.gradle file

Comment: `windowNoTitle` is critical item to make it works in my case.

Answer (score 17):

There are two options I'd like to present:

1. Change the visibility of the SupportActionBar in JAVA code
2. Choose another Style in your project's style.xml

1:
Add getSupportActionBar().hide(); to your onCreate method.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

2:
Another option is to change the style of your Application. Check out the styles.xml in "app->res->values" and change

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 10):

Just use this

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

Answer (score 9):

If you use AppCompat v7, v21

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 8):

Use this to remove title from android app in your Androidmainfest.xml

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

or you can use this in your activity

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Comment: want hide only bottom navigation bar not the status bar. Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 7):

If you have `import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;` and your class extends `ActionBarActivity` then use this in your `OnCreate`:

```
android.support.v7.app.ActionBar AB=getSupportActionBar();
AB.hide();
```

Comment: Out of all the answers here, this is the only one that worked for me!

Answer (score 6):

In the graphical editor, make sure you have chosen your theme at the top.

Answer (score 6):

It's obvious, but the `App Theme` selection in design is just for display a draft during layout edition, is not related to real app looking in cell phone.

Just change the manifest file (`AndroidManifest.xml`) is not enough because the style need to be predefined is `styles.xml`. Also is useless change the layout files.

All proposed solution in `Java` or `Kotlin` has failed for me. Some of them crash the app.  And if one never (like me) uses the title bar in app, the static solution is cleaner.

For me the only solution that works in 2019 (Android Studio 3.4.1) is:

in `styles.xml` (under app/res/values) add the lines:

```
   <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

After in `AndroidManifest.xml` (under app/manifests)

Replace

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

by

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
```

Answer (score 5):

Title bar in android is called Action bar. So if you want to remove it from any specific activity, go to AndroidManifest.xml and add the theme type. Such as `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"`.

Example:

```
<activity
    android:name=".SplashActivity"
    android:noHistory="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 4):

In your `res/values/styles.xml` of modern Android Studio projects (2019/2020) you should be able to change the default parent theme

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

I went one step further and had it look like this

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

This is based on the code generated from the Microsoft PWA builder https://www.pwabuilder.com/

Answer (score 2):

in the graphical layout, you can choose the theme on the toolbar. (the one that looks like a star).

choose the `NoTitleBar` and have fun.

Answer (score 1):

Use this Remove title and image from top.

Before:

```
setContentView(R.layout.actii);
```

Write this code:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change the theme in the design view of your activity to NoActionBar [like the one here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPl0r.png)

Answer (score 1):

To open the Design window:
res->layouts->activity_manifest.xml
then click on the "Design" button, next to "Code" and "Split". On the TOP LEFT Corner.

[image]

Comment: that will just hide it from the design view in android studio.

Answer (score 0):

Go to res/values/themes and change the third line to .NoActionBar like this in both.

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.yourApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
```