# How to delete this bar from Android app?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

I've got this source code from my friend, he implement the navigation drawer menu in it, but I want to delete it. I deleted everything from main.java about the drawer, but I see this in my app:

[image: The White Bar]

**I mean the white bar with the name.**

Here is a layout code:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#fff >





<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/content_frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_app_bar_layout">




        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </FrameLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <include
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                layout="@layout/top_points_bar" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:paddingStart="16dp"
            app:tabPaddingStart="16dp"
            app:tabPaddingEnd="16dp"
            app:tabMinWidth="96dp"
            app:tabGravity="center" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/md_brown_100"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer"
    android:textColor="@color/okurwa"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:theme="@style/MyTabStyle"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_drawer_header"
    app:itemTextAppearance="@style/MyTabTextStyle"
    android:clipToPadding="false">
    <include
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
        android:visibility="gone"
        layout="@layout/nav_drawer_header"
        android:orientation="vertical"

        />





    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nav_drawer_wallet_id"
        android:layout_width="177dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nav_drawer_total_credits"
        android:layout_width="182dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nav_drawer_username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"/>



    <!--<FrameLayout-->
        <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
        <!--android:layout_gravity="bottom"-->
        <!--android:background="@color/md_white_1000"-->
        <!--android:elevation="4dp"-->
        <!--android:layout_marginBottom="-96dp">-->

        <!--<Button android:id="@+id/navigation_button_footer"-->
            <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
            <!--android:text=""-->
            <!--android:textSize="13sp"-->
            <!--android:textColor="@color/md_grey_800"-->
            <!--android:lines="3"-->
            <!--android:gravity="center"-->
            <!--style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton"-->
            <!--android:paddingTop="20dp"-->
            <!--android:paddingLeft="20dp"-->
            <!--android:paddingRight="20dp"-->
            <!--android:paddingBottom="20dp"/>-->

    <!--</FrameLayout>-->

     </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/lay_connection"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/actmain_margintop"
    android:background="#3c3c3c"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_error"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/error_no_internet"
        android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
        android:textSize="@dimen/twentyfive" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/lay_dialog"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="@string/error_no_internet"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
            android:textSize="@dimen/twentyfive" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And also, it will delete a left menu when user will slide it?
Please help me guys! I think I tried all the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `"@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"` in your style.xml file as described here: [remove-android-app-title-bar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31207230/6728524)

or you can add

`getSupportActionBar().hide();`

in `onCreate()` of your activity.

Comment: It removed the app name in this bar, but the bar is existing

Comment: try `getSupportActionBar().hide()`

Comment: `setDisplayShowTitleEnabled` ? Really? The OP wants to remove the `Toolbar` and not hiding the Title! Please be careful about that...

Answer (score 0):

> he implement the navigation drawer menu in it, but I want to delete
>   it. I deleted everything from main.java about the drawer

If you are trying to remove all of the `NavigationDrawer` implementation, Then you'll have to remove `DrawerLayout` and `NavigationDrawer` codes in your xml layout .

Here is the documentation about this : (First learn how it's working and learn the implementation then remove all of them)

https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

So, You'll have to remove this but you didn't really mention about something, About that (*white section*) - (We call it `Toolbar` BTW) and if you are trying to remove this either since i can't see `Toolbar` codes in your xml, Then you'll have to make a big change in your layout.

After the above deletation, Delete the `NavigationView` which it is a part of `NavigationDrawer` implementation.

> And also, it will delete a left menu when user will slide it?

Sure, Yes. After all those, You'll need to remove this file either :

```
@menu/menu_drawer
```

Anyways, I didn't say anything about that `TabLayout` which i couldn't see something with this name on the image you added, So, I need to see the layout preview more than this image...

But, If you want to delete the `Toolbar`, You may want to change or delete the `AppBarLayout` either.

And take a look at this implementation of `CoordinatorLayout`. It will help you to create the new layout:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html